# My C Program operation is stopped

Tags: c

I wrote and ran this code to practice the basic algorithm. but this program operation is stopped. What is the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int bans(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return (*(int *)a - *(int *)b);
}

int main() 
{ 
    int m, i;
    int* arr;
    scanf("%d", &m);
    arr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * m);
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        scanf("%d", arr[i]);
    }
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    qsort(arr, n, sizeof(arr[0]), bans);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d", arr[i]);` --> `scanf("%d", &arr[i]);` or `scanf("%d", arr + i);`, Use `m` instead of `n`.

Comment: Please read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.

Answer (score 2):

1. `scanf` requires a *pointer* to `arr[i]`: `arr + i` would suffice.
2. `sizeof(arr)` is actually `sizeof(int*)`. Use `m` for the number of elements. The idiom you're using only works for *array* types, **not** pointer types.

Answer (score 0):

The primary problem is in the statement

```
  scanf("%d", arr[i]);
```

where `arr[i]` is of type `int`. You need to pass a pointer to type (`int`), like either

```
scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
```

or

```
scanf("%d", arr+i);
```

Enable compiler warning to the highest level, your compiler should warn you about the expected type mismatch.

After that, in this case,

```
  int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
```

is erroneous, as `sizeof(arr)` is the same as `sizeof (int *)`. You don't need a new variable, at all. Use `m`.